# Make a bar being full every 15 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to make a sort of loading bar, I've made this but it won't work... Who can help me??

```
<div id="loader" style="height: 2px; width: 0px; background: green;">
Test
</div>
<script>
$('#loader').animate({width:'100px'}, 15000);
</script>
```

Thank you!

Edit:
This one's working

```
<div id="loader" style="height: 2px; width: 0px; background: green;">
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    function loader(){$('#loader').animate({width:'0px'}, 1).animate({width:'468px'}, 15000, function() {loader()});}
    loader();
});

</script>
```

Thanks to Pahnin

Comment: I don't see anything (no green div)

Comment: @Pekka He meant that the animation is not wroking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/pahnin/d7hWD/1/

Start the animation after document is loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#loader').animate({width:'100px'}, 15000);
});
```

Edit:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     // jQuery
 });
```

The above function is used to run your jQuery code after all the dom elements are loaded, this includes libraries like jQuery too.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/SJVtr/

Are you sure you're loading including jQuery correctly?:

Answer (score 0):

do you mean like :

```
function startLoad(){
  $('#loader').animate({width:'100px'}, 15000);
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#loader').css({'width':'0'});
    startLoad();
  }, 15000);
}
$(document).ready(startLoad);
```

Comment: If you wish to repeat it every 15 sec you may use this http://jsfiddle.net/pahnin/Ye6Pp/
`
function startLoad(){
  $('#loader').animate({width:'100px'}, 15000,function(){
    $('#loader').css({'width':'0'});
    startLoad();
  });
}
$(document).ready(startLoad);
`